ESP32 Bluetooth Pair scanFilter not working properly
I am trying to make a bluetooth device with esp32 s3. Pairing should work like a headfone. At the First start, any device can connect my ble ESP32 after connecting I will add in whitelist this device which is connetted my esp32 new. even if this divice disconnect only this device can see my bluetooth network and only this device can connect this network. For this I saw this code setScanFilter(true, true); The logic of the code is exactly what I want, but it doesn't work as I imagined. After a phone connects to the network, it cannot reconnect to the same network. Moreover, a PC can see the network when no phone is connected, but it cannot connect either. However, what I want is this: once a phone connects to the network, whether it is currently connected or not, only that phone should be able to see and connect to the network.
this my test code:
#include <BLEDevice.h>
#include <BLEServer.h>
#include <BLEAdvertising.h>

BLEServer* pServer = nullptr;
bool deviceConnected = false;
bool oldDeviceConnected = false;
BLEAddress whitelistDevice("00:00:00:00:00:00");

// BLEServerCallbacks sınıfı
class MyServerCallbacks : public BLEServerCallbacks {
  void onConnect(BLEServer* pServer, esp_ble_gatts_cb_param_t* param) override {

    whitelistDevice = BLEAddress(param->connect.remote_bda);
    Serial.print("Device added to whitelist: ");
    Serial.println(whitelistDevice.toString().c_str());
    delay(500);

    deviceConnected = true;
  }

  void onDisconnect(BLEServer* pServer) {
    deviceConnected = false;
  }
};

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  // BLE cihazını başlat
  BLEDevice::init("truefalse");
  // Sunucuyu oluştur ve callback ayarla
  pServer = BLEDevice::createServer();
  pServer->setCallbacks(new MyServerCallbacks());
  // Reklam oluştur
  BLEAdvertising* pAdvertising = BLEDevice::getAdvertising();
  pAdvertising->setScanFilter(false, false);  // Whitelist'i etkinleştir
  pAdvertising->start();
  Serial.println("Advertising started without whitelist.");
}

void loop() {
  // Bağlantı kesildiğinde reklamları yeniden başlat
  if (!deviceConnected && oldDeviceConnected) {
    delay(500);  // BLE yığını için bekleme

    BLEAdvertising* pAdvertising = BLEDevice::getAdvertising();
    // Reklamları durdur
    pAdvertising->stop();
    Serial.println("Advertising stopped.");    
    delay(500);
    // Beyaz liste filtresini etkinleştir
    BLEDevice::whiteListAdd(whitelistDevice);

    Serial.print("Device added to whitelist: ");
    Serial.println(whitelistDevice.toString().c_str());

    pAdvertising->setScanFilter(true, true);  // Beyaz liste filtresini etkinleştir
    // Reklamları yeniden başlat
    pAdvertising->start();
    Serial.println("Advertising restarted with whitelist filter."); 

    Serial.println("Advertising restarted.");
    oldDeviceConnected = deviceConnected;
  }
  // Bağlantı kurulduğunda durum güncellemesi
  if (deviceConnected && !oldDeviceConnected) {
    oldDeviceConnected = deviceConnected;
    Serial.println("Device connected.");
  }
  delay(1000);
}

